# The SE blog is missing an image

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

A little embarrassing; [the blog post about the "new image uploader"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) has a missing image:

[image]

Comment: Ever since we moved to a new blogging platform we've had broken images. The best way to raise the issue, I think, is to [submit a pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pulls).

Comment: @JonEricson is there a helpful tutorial for that anywhere?

Comment: [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) might be helpful for you. You'll need to [create a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/about-forks/) first. Or [create an issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues) if you prefer. (Pulls requests are more likely to be acted upon, I suspect.)

Comment: Haha, that's quite ironic :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a mass migration of all of our old blog assets, this should be fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

I have submitted a pull request to add this image again. The image doesn't seem to have been copied from the old platform, so I just got it from the Wayback Machine.

https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/pull/198